# Google Analytics Custom dimension doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, analytics, custom-dimensions

I'm having some troubles with the custom dimension that i set in my file's header. The analytics is linked to my site because i get on the analytics the real time count.

That been said, as you can see in the code there is a JS variable **iduser** it contains the value of a div that has the current ID of the user connected.

I created the dimension based on **Hit** so i make some interactions in my page but i don't get the value of userid in my **custom reports**

I was wondering if some of you can help and tell me where my set up is wrong ?

*NOTE: The name of the dimension in my GA is : **iduser***

Thank you so much in advance

```js
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

 
 iduser = $('#userid').text();

 

 ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxxxx', 'auto');

 ga('set','userid', iduser); 

 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 3):

**The syntax is wrong**. You want to specify the dimension/metric ID (0-20) and not its name (which makes sense since names can change, dimension/metric IDs never do):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets#id=%22sending_data%22

For instance for the 1st custom dimension:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'something');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,i did as you advised me but i still don't get any value, my table of "customized reports" is always empty. I set it by "Hit" instead of "Session". i put instead of 'something" the name of the variable 'userid'. I still don't get anything. I tried passing a static value like a random number after doing some interactions in nthe page but it still doesn't show anything. Are the ids added after minutes or after 24 hours ?

Comment: Can you see your custom dimension data being set properly by your browser: ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Comment: I see the value of the iduser showing up properly in the result of the chrome extension as follows : dimension1       (&cd1)  222    i had to use the following code :  ga('set', 'dimension1', iduser);

Comment: I'm facing similar issue. I see the values passed over in cd1 & cd2. I had also set up the custom dimensions in admin settings page. but could not see the passed over values. Any help will be highly appreciable.